# Setting a variable in a jquery-function

Tags: jquery

ok, I know, the title may sound a little weird...

Following problem:

I have a jquery function like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myFunction = function(opts){
        var settings = {
           params: {}
        };
    }

    if ( options ) { 
      $.extend( settings, options );
    }

}
```

Now, the function is applied to an element like this:

```
$('#elem').myFunction({'data':'test','data2': 'test2'});
```

How do I access the settings-property from outside of the function?

Means, after the function is initialized, I want to change some of the settings - I can't figure out how, though.

Any ideas?

(hope it's not too confusing what I wrote :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to take the variable up into higher level scope.

```
(function ($) {

    // we expose your variable up here
    var settings = {
    };

    $.fn.myFunction = function (opts) {
        // ...instead of down here
        // do something with settings, like:
        opts = $.extend({}, settings, opts);
    }

    // you can then access a "shared" copy of your variable even here
    if (options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

If you have to expose it further, you'll just have to work along that same gist.

As a side note however, do note that calling `$.extend(settings, options)` will modify the `settings` variable. A nice way to do the same thing without modifying the original `settings` value is to call `$.extend()` on an empty object, and just cache the return like I did in the first `$.extend()` call in my example.

```
var modified_options = $.extend({}, settings, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for that... But I need to change the settings when I init the object without calling a function of the object. When I try to access «settings» from outside the object, I get an error saying that «settings» is not defined.